# DIODE as capacitor?

Tags: diodes, capacitance, zener, esd

How does Diode act like a capacitor when voltage across diode is less than forward voltage spec. Basically when diode is turned off? What is its usual capacitance when diode (zener) is turned off.

Comment: Look up varactor diode - they are used extensively for VHF and UHF tuners

Answer (score 4):

A diode is made when P-doped material and N-doped material are put side by side. P-doped material has an excess of holes for electrons and N-doped material has an excess of electrons. Electrons can only go where there's a hole, which is why silicon has to be doped to conduct anything -- in a silicon lattice, the electrons are all tied up in bonds.

When the diode is forward biased, all the electrons are able to find a hole to move to and current can flow. Note that electrons flow from the negative terminal to the positive terminal of the battery, which is exactly opposite the flow of current. In a simple diode/battery circuit where the positive side of the battery is connected to the P side of the diode, the electrons enter the N side first, jump across to the P side because there's room for them, and then enter the positive terminal of the battery.

If you flip the battery, the electrons meet holes on the P side, which they will fill, then they meet the electrons on the other side of the gap. There's no room for them to go, so no current flows, and charge builds up on opposite sides of the junction like a miniature parallel plate capacitor.

The derivation for an actual capacitance value is lengthy so I'll link it [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter3/ch3_3.htm). You want equation 3.3.24.